# Docker-compose backend не подключается в БД

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

Здравствуйте новичок с docker поэтому может вопрос и глупый. Есть docker-compose файл в нем разворачивается db и backend, который подключается к db

```
`version: '3.7'
services:
  app: 
    build: .
    container_name: backend

    ports:
      - "8008:8000"
    command: bash -c "uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0"

    restart: always
  
  db:
    image:  postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: filmass
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 316497258
      POSTGRES_DB: "film_assistant"
    
    restart: always`
```

База данных запускается и говорит, что готова принимать подключения, но когда мой back end пытается подключиться прилетает ошибка.

```
 raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5432)


ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.
```

Пытался подключаться с разными значениями host и ports менял прослушивающий порт на 32700 и тот же результат

конфиг файл

```
DB_USER = environ.get("DB_USER", "user")
DB_PASSWORD = environ.get("DB_PASSWORD", "password")
DB_HOST = environ.get("DB_HOST", "localhost")
DB_NAME = environ.get("DB_NAME", "database")

DATABASE_URL = (f"postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:5432/{DB_NAME}")
```

кусок кода, где пытаюсь подключиться к базе

```
database = Database(DATABASE_URL)
metadata = MetaData()
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
```

Если нужна ещё какая-то инфа пишите добавлю. Заранее спасибо

Comment: «с разными значениями host» — какими именно? Хост `db` пробовали?

Comment: 0.0.0.0, localhost, 127.0.0.1 . С db не пробовал сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо большое реально заработало. Во всех гайдах использовались цифы, я вот и пытался